# How to link jhipster command to existing repo?

Tags: node.js, jhipster

Suppose I cloned and modified jhipster-generator and I want to launch the application with:

```
jhipster
```

running this command will trigger the actual jhipster-generator repository on https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster.

How would I link it to my current repository locally which has been modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As advised in another question you posted, read the JHipster [contributing guide](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#set-npmyarn-to-use-the-cloned-project). Look at the paragraph where it explains that you must use `npm link`

Comment: Thanks alot. I just fixed all the issues with this answer altogether.